# Create Custom TableViewCell using XIB-File

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I am using Xib file on which I drag and drop a **TableViewController**. My goal is to use **custom cells** on the TableViewController.
I edit the class in the properties panel of the first cell to a Specific name(Let's say MyCustomCell) to get a custom cell.
After **pressing Enter** in the cell name editing field, Visual Studio generates the corresponding code behind file MyCustomCell.cs with designer class file.

So far so good. But when I try to compile the project I get this error : 
**Table views with embedded sections and cells are only supported in storyboard documents**

Is there a way to do this with a Xib file ?

Comment: Not supported by Apple, use a Storyboard instead

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover. So Storyboard are the only way ?

Comment: Do you have a specific issue with using a Storyboard?

Comment: I'm really newbie to xamarin ios. I don't really have a correct answer for your question. I just know that we used to use Xib, and maybe this have something to do with the navigation on storyboard.

Comment: Don't add `TableViewController` into xib, one xib file can only include one viewcontroller. You should use Storyboard instead.